# android manifest fullscreen causes my app crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fullscreen

Made My first app. Just after creating I tried make it Full screen. It says "Unfortunately your app has been stopped."

Android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActiviy.java

```
package com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

logcat

```
03-25 22:05:14.257 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-25 22:05:14.427 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-25 22:05:14.427 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15038: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-25 22:05:14.427 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15042: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-25 22:05:14.437 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f3c600)
03-25 22:05:14.437 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5578)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:340)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:273)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5578) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-25 22:05:17.087 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen D/Process: killProcess, pid=5289
03-25 22:05:17.087 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen D/Process: dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
03-25 22:05:17.087 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen D/Process: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
03-25 22:05:17.087 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen D/Process: android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:956)
03-25 22:05:17.087 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen D/Process: com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:108)
03-25 22:05:17.087 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen D/Process: java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
03-25 22:05:17.087 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen D/Process: java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
03-25 22:05:17.087 5289-5289/com.example.nirmal.projectfullscreen D/Process: dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this My guess is that you are getting an error that `AppCompatActivity` requires `Theme.AppCompat` or another theme that inherits from that. If so, you would need to see if there is a `Fullscreen` variation of `Theme.AppCompat` that you can use, or else remove `appcompat-v7` and work with the native action bar.

Comment: Another way for fullscreen is change appcompatactivity to Activity in Mainactivity class.

Comment: Sorry, I could not format the logcat message.

Comment: @Nirmal, did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: I didn't try it. But after change the extends class to "Activity" from "Appcompatactivity" and change the "setcontentview(R.id.content_main)" worked fine :)

Comment: @Nirmal, but you should use `AppCompatActivity` not `Activity`. And `AppCompatActivity` actually extends `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `AppCompatActivity` and thus your theme should inherit `Theme.AppCompat`.

*You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.*

Use this theme:

```
<style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

In your manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme"
```